# Code comments in a ASP .Net projects

Tags: asp.net, coding-style

I'm used to work on my on smaller projects where I normally is the only contributor but now I'm working on a ASP .Net C# project where others will be working with my code later on.

I do believe I do comment my C# code in a professional way but I have never bothered writing comments in my ASPX pages except in JavaScript code.

Is there any "standard" that ASP .Net developers work with?

Do I put info in comments about actions generated in Code Behind to simplify reading the page or is that overkill?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strive for self-documenting code (requires fewer comments).

Follow common patterns (in-house or industry)

Use (sparingly) comments 'of high level Intent' to explain non-obvious code.

Comment: Instead of "non-obvious code" I would use: abstract concepts and algorithms. What I mean with that is you do want to document things that do not change and what you are actual doing and not what the code does. The code tells you what it does, the comments tells you what you want it to do and that shouldn't change.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: Yes, that's what I mean. Noted and updated. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Understand what is (possible) needs explanation if viewed by other. Use GhostDoc plugin to write comments quickly, but do remember to verify comments written by plugin. Comments should be self explanatory.

Comment: GhostDoc does not support commenting in ASPX/HTML/XML

Comment: Yes it does not. HTML however is easier to understand, else you can put comments anyway. Comments in HTML is not recommended as it increase the page size and comes to user browser (may reduce your privacy), however sometimes might be useful as used by some crawlers. Use server side comments if you need to put some sensitive info